# How to get payment methods to load when shipping step has been removed

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I have removed the shipping step from the Magento 2 one page checkout by editing the shipping.js file in this location - ***vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view***

I set the visibility to false:
`visible: ko.observable(false)`

And then I comment out the step registration:

```
stepNavigator.registerStep(
    'shipping',
    '',
    $t('Shipping'),
    this.visible, _.bind(this.navigate, this),
    10
);
```

The shipping step goes away just like a want it to but then no payment methods are being loaded. I have tried to find the reason but so far no luck. Help me please :)